# How to solve server response issue for android apps

Tags: java, android, server, dns, xampp

When i redirect android app to my local xampp server i am getting expected output from server. like below

[image]

Problem is when i redirect my app to a real ip or a domain server problem occurs. Here is my code.

```
 protected String doInBackground(String[] paramparameterForURL) {

        try{
            //serv_url="http://www.eurekabd.com";//shakil/"+paramparameterForURL[0];
            URL url = new URL("http://www.eurekabd.com/shakil/home.php"/*serv_url*/);
            //URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.109/shakil/shakil.php"/*serv_url*/);
            //URL url = new URL("http://144.48.2.11/shakil/shakil.php"/*serv_url*/);
            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();

            postDataParams.put("name", "abhay");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(300 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(300 /* milliseconds */);
            //conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";

                while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);

                    break;
                }
                in.close();
                return sb.toString();
            }
            else {
                return new String("false : "+responseCode);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Problems are**

1.Server WWW.eurecabd.com is returning exception NULL like below
[image]

2.real ip server is returning  empty like bellow

[image]

How to solve the issue or what is the issue? Is it in coding or in network protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the response of the different servers , also you should modified this :

```
conn.setConnectTimeout(300 /* milliseconds */);
```

300 milliseconds is too low for a connection timeout , remember is in milliseconds.

Comment: I tested my app previously. after all calculation i threshold the time to 300mS. Although server respond with in 255 mS. Is there any thing else i can do brother.

Comment: Check the server response in your web browser

Comment: If server response is like this is there any problem.Array ( [0] => 1235 [1] => 1238 ) 2